# PHP Recursive Function, return error

Tags: php, arrays, return

I create a PHP function to test if `$var exist and is not empty`.

But, But I have a problem that I can't identify :

- In my foreach, return false is ignored because another 'return' return first.

LOOK :

```
    function notEmpty($var, $r=false){
    if(gettype($var)=='string' OR gettype($var)=='integer'){
        if($r==false){
            if(isset($var) AND @!empty($var)){
                return true;
            }else{return false;}
        }else{
            if(!isset($var) AND @empty($var)){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }elseif(gettype($var)=='array'){
        foreach($var as $val){
            if(gettype($val)=='array'){
                notEmpty($val, true);
            }else{
                if(empty($val) OR $val==''){echo "string";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }else{return null;}
}
```

I call my function like : 
- `notEmpty(array($val1, $val2, $val3));`

Comment: What is `$r` meant to express in that code? You better should use self explaining names for your variables.

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: You need to somehow react to the return value of the _inner_ call to `notEmpty()`. Currently you completely ignore it.

Comment: Your if(empty($val) OR $val=='') condition is redundant

Comment: redundant ? I dont' understand ?

Comment: $r for recursive, but it's a test

Comment: @arkascha, what do you want to say ?

Comment: @Azee What I want to say? Well, what I wrote... Do you have a specific aspect you do not understand in that?

Comment: If `$r` is for "recursive", then why does that flag only get used in the part of the code _not_ performing recursion?

Comment: @arkascha, because this function make me crazy. I don't understand how to make it works.

Comment: @Azee Which is (again) not an answer to a question. You seem to repeat that you have an issue. We know that.

Comment: Ok, So in my function, where is the problem ? I don't call recursive at the good moment ?

Comment: I already answered that further up: you _do_ make a recursive call, but you currently ignore its result.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is more or less what you are looking for:

```
<?php

function notEmpty($array, $recursive=false) {
    $empty = array_filter($array, function($element) use ($recursive) {
        if (is_array($element) && $recursive) {
            return !notEmpty($element);
        } else {
            return empty($element);
        }
    });
    return 0===count($empty);
}

var_dump(notEmpty([1, 2, 3]));
var_dump(notEmpty(['foo', '', 'bar']));
var_dump(notEmpty(['foo', null, 'bar']));
var_dump(notEmpty(['foo', [1,2,3], 'bar']));
var_dump(notEmpty(['foo', [1,null,3], 'bar']));
var_dump(notEmpty(['foo', [1,null,3], 'bar'], true));
```

The output of that is:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```